# Soldering tiny connectors

Tags: soldering

I recently purchased this item to use with an arduino:

http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9105

My problem is that I realized after the fact that this wasn't attached to the breakout board. Are these connections too small to be soldered by hand? What is the smallest distance between connections that can realistically be soldered by hand?

Comment: You might check out some of the SMD soldering tutorials at http://CuriousInventor.com

Comment: See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/ and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4678.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any problems hand-soldering connectors like that. I use a Metcal soldering station with a mini-hoof cartridge. I tack the connector down at two opposite corners, making sure it is positioned properly using a stereo microscope, apply plenty of jelly flux, and drag-solder each row.

Comment: But not many people have such expensive equipment...

Comment: It wasn't expensive: I bought my Metcal system second-hand for £120 and my microscope cost me £65.